# PostgreSQL: DISTINCT ON table MAX of another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Release table (id, manga_id, chapterization_id) and Chapterization table (id, chapter).

Let's assume I have

Release

```
id | manga_id | chapterization_id
--------------------------------
1  | 44       | 333
2  | 55       | 222
3  | 66       | 777
4  | 44       | 888
5  | 44       | 999
```

Chapterization

```
id  | chapter
------------
111 | 60
222 | 70
333 | 80
444 | 90
777 | 100
888 | 120
999 | 110
```

I want to fetch the maximum (latest) chapter of each manga_id.
Manga 44 has 3 chapterizations, but I want to fetch the latest chapter of it which is 120

So the final result would be releases with id [2,3,4]
Any idea how to write such a query in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `join` and the `distinct on` clause:

```
select distinct on (r.manga_id) r.manga_id, c.id, c.chapter
from release r join
     chapterization c
     on r.chapterization_id = c.id
order by r.manga_id, c.chapter desc;
```

Comment: Thanks, never thought of using order by to get the highest value

Answer (score 2):

Try -

```
select r.manga_id, max(c.chapter)
  from release r
  join chapterization c
    on r.chapterization_id = c.id
 group by r.manga_id
```

Based on your comment, if you also want the r.id you can use either of the following methods. First is a join with an inline view. Second is a subquery. Both should have the same result and give you what you want.

```
select r.manga_id, r.id, c.chapter
  from release r
  join chapterization c
    on r.chapterization_id = c.id
  join (select r.manga_id, max(c.chapter) as max_chapter
          from release r
          join chapterization c
            on r.chapterization_id = c.id
         group by r.manga_id) x
    on r.manga_id = x.manga_id
   and c.chapter = x.max_chapter
```

or

```
select r.manga_id, r.id, c.chapter
  from release r
  join chapterization c
    on r.chapterization_id = c.id
 where c.chapter = (select max(c2.chapter)
                      from release r2
                      join chapterization c2
                        on r2.chapterization_id = c2.id
                     where r2.manga_id = r.manga_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works it doesn't return r.id column if I add it to SELECT .. r.id has to be in group by or an aggregated function

Comment: I would appreciate it if you can get release id using group by